# TypeError: class method is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am building a Discord bot using `discord.js` and I am facing a problem that I think is more related to JS OOP. With my current class

```
class DiscordBot {
    constructor() {
        this.bot = new Client({ intents: [...] });

        // setup listeners
        this.bot.once('ready', this.onReady);
    }

    async onReady(client) {
        console.log('Ready!');
        this.bot = client;

        this.text_channel = await this.bot.channels.fetch(id)

        this.test();
    }

    test() {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

I cannot call `this.test()` because of the error:

> `TypeError: this.test is not a function`

I really cannot work this through.

Node version: `v16.8.0`

Comment: reproducing this in node v16.2.0 worked just fine, not getting an error

Answer (score 1):

that is becuase `test` is defined in the `DiscordBot` prototype not in the class instance, you can fix it by:

1.bind `test` to the class instance its self:

```
constructor() {
        this.bot = new Client({ intents: [...] });
        this.bot.once('ready', this.onReady);
        this.test = this.test.bind(this)
    }
```

2.define it as instance field:

```
test = () =>{ }
```

Comment: It still does not work, same error. I checked the syntax, I also tried renaming the function... Nothing.

Comment: @davidem. is the error message still the same?

Comment: Yes, and on the same line.

Comment: This will not fix the issue, binding is use to bind the scope of function, this.test = this.test.bind(this); will bind the scope of test to this so that this will be accessible to test function. It will not make any change in invoking the function

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.bind()` in your `constructor` like this:

```
this.test = this.test.bind(this);
```

This way you can access other methods in your class. Read more about [Javascript binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: This will not fix the issue, binding is use to bind the scope of function, this.test = this.test.bind(this); will bind the scope of test to this so that this will be accessible to test function. It will not make any change in invoking the function

Answer (score 0):

try

`this.bot.once('ready', () => this.onReady());`

instead of

`this.bot.once('ready', this.onReady);`

Comment: Event `ready` is not fired, thus I can't see the `console.log('Ready!');`

Comment: can you try adding  `setTimeout(() => this.onReady(), 500);`. inside constructor and check onReady is getting invoked

Comment: Okay, I actually didn't call the function, I had put `() => this.onReady`. But now it says that the property `bot` is `undefined`. Error in method `onReady`

Comment: add `this.onReady = this.onReady.bind(this)` inside constructor

Comment: Thank you! Now it works. Quite a dirty solution imho, coming from Python/Java at least.

Comment: you can make it an arrow function instead of binding in the constructor